# Getting random path hierarchy for CCK fields inside form array

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, cck

I have created a custom entity and i'm using CCK fields. Each bundle has it's own fields. For example:

```
function MYMODULE_install() {
  // Check if our field is not already created.
  if (!field_info_field('field_myField')) {
    $field = array(
        'field_name' => 'date_field',
        'type' => 'list_text',
    );
    field_create_field($field);
}

//Enable is executed only once.
function bundle_callback_enable() {

     // Create the instance on the bundle.
    $instance = array(
        'field_name' => 'date_field',
        'entity_type' => 'payment_method',
        'label' => 'Expiration Date',
        'bundle' => 'card',
        'required' => TRUE,
        'settings' => array();

    field_create_instance($instance);
}
```

My bundles are created from individual modules, so in each install file i am creating the respective fields.

Yesterday i tried to add validation callback functions in those fields and i saw something weird inside form array. Fields with type="text" had the path:

```
$form[field_name]['und'][0][value] //<! expectable
```

but fields with type='list_text' had only the path:

```
$form[field_name]['und'] //<! unexpectable
```

I couldn't find any solution and i've solved it with this:

```
function &get_cck_path_value( $field_name, &$form_path) {

  $field = null
  if ( isset( $form_path[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE] ) ) {
     $field = &$form_path[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE]
  }elseif(isset($form_path[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE][0])) {
    $field =  &$form_path[$field_name][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  }
  return $field;
}
```

I don't like this approach. Is too hucky. Can you tell me if that is a cck feature or bug?
I can't understand when it decides where to put the values( All the process is fulfilled through the "field_attach_form( ... )" )?

Have you faced any problem like this?

Thanks in advance.

Thandem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are seeing the abbreviated form field in validation because the field had no value entered into it and no default value was defined for it. There is no value, so no array is present to store the value.

Comment: Ed it isn't the abbreviated form field. When i'm using the dsm function i'm seeing in fields with type list_text this: